# Lottery odds calculated in your head, or pen and paper.

Tags: algorithms

So I am working out the odds for a lottery, picking 4 numbers between 1-35.

The equation is:

$$\mbox{odds}=\frac{35\cdot 34\cdot 33\cdot 32}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4}=52360$$

Yes, I can work this out on a calculator with ease.

However, how can I work this out on pen and paper, or in my head with ease?

Are there any type of methods or cheats I could use to calculate this quickly?

Comment: Do you want to find the exact answer or is approximate ok?

Comment: Either or @NickH

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update: I got a very good Idea from comments so I updated the answer:**
$$T=\large\require{cancel}\frac{35\cdot34\cdot\color{purple}{\cancel{33}^{11}}\cdot\color{blue}{\cancel{32}^{\color{red}{\cancel{8}^{4}}}}}{1\cdot\color{red}{\cancel{2}}\cdot\color{purple}{\cancel{3}}\cdot\color{blue}{\cancel{4}}}=35\cdot34\cdot44$$
Now a good fact is square of a two digit number can be done by multiplying the tens digit by its successor and just appending 25 at the end like $35^2=\widehat{3\cdot4}\;25=1225$
$$\large35\cdot34\cdot44=(35^2-35)\cdot44=(1225-35)\cdot44=1190\cdot44$$

So:
$$\large T=1190\cdot44\\\large=1190\cdot4\cdot11\\\large=(4000+400+360)\cdot11\\\large=4760\cdot11\\\large=(47600+4760)=52360$$

Comment: Pretty typesetting :)

Comment: Since it's $34$ and $35$ I think it would be faster to multiply $35\times35$ and subtract 35 from the result. for all numbers of the form $n5^2$ where $n$ is the tens digit, the answer is $n\times(n+1)$ for the first digits and 25 for the last: $35^2 \Rightarrow 3\times 4 = 12$, put $25$ behind and you get $1225$. $1225-35 = 1190$.

Comment: Very nice use of colour. +1

Comment: @fvel: Alternatively: 35 × 34 = 70 × 17 = 700 + 490 = 1190.

Comment: @fvel just added the good Idea

Comment: @ADG You could also mention that the trick is best used on digits of the form $\overset{10}{n}\overset{1}{5}$. An alternative way of doing $1190\cdot4$ could be $1190\cdot4 = (1200-10)\cdot4 = 4800-40 = 4760$ or doubling twice $1190\cdot4 = 2380\cdot2 = 4760$. A nice approximation would also be $1190\cdot44 \approx 1000\cdot 50 = 50.000$. This could be a way of checking the answer, as $50.000\approx 52.360$, or $34\cdot35\cdot44 \approx 30\cdot40\cdot40 = 48.000$.

Answer (score 4):

If you're happy with something very approximate, that you can do in your head, $35\times 34\times 33\times 32$ is about $33^4$. $33^2$ is about $1,100$, so the numerator is about $1.2$ million.  The denominator is $1\times 2\times 3\times 4$ is about $25$, which is $100/4$ so the answer is about $1.2$ million divided by a hundred, times four, which is $48,000$.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{35\cdot34\cdot33\cdot32}{2\cdot3\cdot4}=35\cdot17\cdot11\cdot8=595\cdot11\cdot8=6545\cdot8=52360$

Answer (score 3):

On pen and paper, this is just a few multiplies.  It is good to cancel factors first, getting $35*34*11*4$  Then look for easy ones.  I would now go to $140*34*11$.  Since multiplying by $11$ is just an addition, I would next to $140*34$

In your head, you probably won't get an exact answer, so look for approximations. I would say $35/4! \approx 1.5$ and multiplying two of the other factors gives about $1000$, so we have $1.5*34*1000 \approx 51000$  Knowing lots of arithmetic facts helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use "completing the squares" a lot for exact mental calculations.

$35.34.44 = 35.(39-5).(39+5)=35.(39.39-5.5)$
$= 35.(40.40-40-39-25)=35.(1521-25)=35.(1500-4)$
$=7.5(1500-4)=7.(7500-20)$

$=49000+3500-140=52500-140=52360$

Yes, superficially this looks quite long. However:

- Each step is very tiny
- Very little working memory is used

Answer (score 2):

$${35\cdot34\cdot33\cdot32\over1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}={5\cdot7\cdot2\cdot17\cdot3\cdot11\cdot8\cdot4\over3\cdot8}=10\cdot7\cdot17\cdot11\cdot4$$

The factor of $10$ will just give an extra $0$ at the end.  The "difficult" multiplications are

$$7\cdot17=70+49=119$$

$$119\cdot11=1190+119=1309$$

and

$$1309\cdot4=5236$$

so the final answer is $52360$.

The trickiest part (for me) was getting the carry correct when adding $1190+119$.  Alternatively, you can do the first two multiplications as

$$17\cdot11=170+17=187$$
and
$$7\cdot187=7(200-13)=1400-91=1309$$