# Find the limit without using Maclaurin series

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Find a limit,
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos{(1-\cos{(1-\cos x)})}}{x^8}$$
without using Maclaurin series. My attempt was to use L'hopital's rule but that's just too much, and chances of not making a mistake trough repetitive differentiation are very low.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Use repetitively "$1-\cos x=2\sin^2 x/2$"
$$\newcommand{\b}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\f}{\frac}
\newcommand{\t}{\text}
\newcommand{\u}{\underbrace}
$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos{(1-\cos{(1-\cos x)})}}{x^8}
=\lim_{x\to0}\f{2\sin^2\b{\sin^2\b{\sin^2\b{\f x2}}}}{x^8}\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\f{2\sin^2\b{\color{red}{\sin^2\b{\color{blue}{\sin^2\b{\color{green}{\f x2}}}}}}}{\b{\color{red}{\sin^2\b{\color{blue}{\sin^2\b{\color{green}{\f x2}}}}}}^2}.\f{\b{\color{red}{\sin^2\b{\color{blue}{\sin^2\b{\color{green}{\f x2}}}}}}^2}{\b{\color{blue}{\sin^2\b{\color{green}{\f x2}}}}^4}.\f{\b{\color{blue}{\sin^2\b{\color{green}{\f x2}}}}^4}{\b{\color{green}{\f x2}}^8}.\b{\f 12}^8
\\=\lim_{x\to0}\f1{128}\b{\f{\sin\b{\color{fuchsia}{\sin^2\b{\sin^2\b{\f x2}}}}}{\color{fuchsia}{\sin^2\b{\sin^2\b{\f x2}}}}}^2.\b{\f{\sin\b{\color{purple}{\sin^2\b{\f x2}}}}{\color{purple}{\sin^2\b{\f x2}}}}^4.\b{\f{\sin\b{\color{crimson}{\f x2}}}{\color{crimson}{\f x2}}}^8
\\={\large\f1{128}}\quad\b{\because \f{\sin x}x=1}$$

Comment: I wanted to give the same hint!

Comment: @Transcedental edited

Comment: @sciona did you see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077774/lottery-odds-calculated-in-your-head-or-pen-and-paper/1077784#1077784) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921336/how-to-find-lim-x-to-0-frac1-sinx-frac1-arcsinx/921347#921347)

Comment: @ADG =P I see .. nice formatting.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use $1-\cos t = 2\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}$ and the chain rule for limit. (ask if you need further hint)

Comment: Oh i'm an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: @Transcendental wc :)